# IOS keychain saves or loads failing

Tags: ios, keychain

I am using this class to load and save a userid and password to the ios keychain.

Every once in a while either the load or save is failing on a real device. I can't tell which.

Am I doing anything wrong in this code?

Is there a better way I should be doing this?

This code is based on code at https://gist.github.com/mlapointe/6e88a9f059f1cc0dabec

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface KeychainHelper : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary * keychainItem;


- (void)saveKeychainWithUserId:(NSString *)userId andPassword: (NSString *)password;

- (NSString *)getPassword;

- (NSString *)getUserId;

@end 

#import <Security/Security.h>

@interface KeychainHelper ()

@end


@implementation KeychainHelper


- (NSMutableDictionary *)createEmptyKeychainItem {
    //Let's create an empty mutable dictionary:
    _keychainItem = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    //Populate it with the data and the attributes we want to use.

    _keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecClass] = (__bridge id)kSecClassInternetPassword;
    _keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible] = (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock;

    _keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecAttrServer] = @"myapp.com";

    _keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecReturnData] = (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue;
    _keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecReturnAttributes] = (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue;

    return nil;
}

- (void)saveKeychainWithUserId: (NSString *) userId andPassword: (NSString *)password {
    [self createEmptyKeychainItem];

    // Check if this keychain item already exists.
    if(SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)_keychainItem, NULL) == noErr) {
        // Item Already Exists == Update instead
        [self updateKeychainWithUserId:userId andPassword:password];
    } else {
        //Item does not exist -- create new
        _keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecValueData] = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        _keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount] = userId;

        OSStatus sts = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)_keychainItem, NULL);
        if (sts != noErr) {
            NSLog(@"Error Code while inserting keychain: %d", (int)sts);
        }
    }
}

- (void)updateKeychainWithUserId:(NSString *)userId andPassword:(NSString *)password {
    NSMutableDictionary *attributesToUpdate = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    attributesToUpdate[(__bridge id)kSecValueData] = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    attributesToUpdate[(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount] = userId;

    // Must set these back to false for SecItemUpdate to work
    _keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecReturnData] = (__bridge id)kCFBooleanFalse;
    _keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecReturnAttributes] = (__bridge id)kCFBooleanFalse;

    OSStatus sts = SecItemUpdate((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)_keychainItem, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributesToUpdate);
    if (sts != noErr) {
        NSLog(@"Error Code while updating keychain: %d", (int)sts);
    }
}

- (NSString *)getPassword {
    CFDictionaryRef result = nil;

    [self createEmptyKeychainItem];

    OSStatus sts = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)_keychainItem, (CFTypeRef *)&result);

    if (sts == noErr) {
        NSDictionary *resultDict = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)result;
        NSData *passwordData = resultDict[(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
        NSString *password = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:passwordData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        return password;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No Keychain found while getting password, Error Code: %d", (int)sts);
        return nil;
    }
}

- (NSString *)getUserId {

    CFDictionaryRef result = nil;

    [self createEmptyKeychainItem];

    OSStatus sts = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)_keychainItem, (CFTypeRef *)&result);

    if (sts == noErr) {
        NSDictionary *resultDict = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)result;

        return resultDict[(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No Keychain found while getting userId, Error Code: %d", (int)sts);
        return nil;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: try this https://gist.github.com/dhoerl/1170641

Comment: what's the error when it fails ?

Comment: @wain I am not sure which is failing since I don't have the logs from the device.